# function not working when i click button?

Tags: javascript, function, timer, addeventlistener

when i click my button, a timer is supposed to display a countdown timer. But the button does not work.

```js
let timerCounter = document.getElementById("timer-counter");
let timer;
let timerCount;

function startTimer() {
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    timerCount--;
    timerElement.textContent = "Time; " + timerCount;
    if (timerCount === 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  });
}
startButton.addEventListener("click", startTimer);
```

Comment: You have something called `timerCounter` but you're trying to update something called `timerElement`.

Comment: Always check your console for errors first.

Comment: you need give a initial value to `timerCount`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found so far:

- You are decrementing the `timerCount`, need to specify the initial value for it to work.
- You're using `timerElement` instead of `timerCounter` that you've declared.
- You must pass the second args to the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) which is `delay`.

```js
const timerCounter = document.getElementById('timer-counter');
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-button');

let timer;
let timerCount = 30;

startButton.addEventListener('click', startTimer);

function startTimer() {
  timer = setInterval(function () {
    timerCount--;
    timerCounter.textContent = 'Time; ' + timerCount;
    if (timerCount === 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="timer-counter"></div>
<button id="start-button">Start</button>
```

Comment: This has it's own problems, spamming the start button makes your counter go down faster and even go into negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach that avoids some of the problems with global variables. The function the listener calls initialises the count, and then returns a new function (a closure) that is called when the button is clicked. It also uses `setTimeout` which I find more easy to understand.

```js
// Cache your elements
const counter = document.querySelector('#counter');
const startButton = document.querySelector('button');

// Initialise your count variable
function startTimer(count = 30) {

  // Return a function that is called from
  // the listener
  return function loop () {

    // Disabled the button once it's been clicked
    if(!startButton.disabled) startButton.disabled = true;      

    counter.textContent = `Time: ${count}`;
    if (count > 0) {
      setTimeout(loop, 500, --count);
    }
  }

  loop();

}

// Call startTimer to initialise the count, and return
// a new function that is used as the listener
startButton.addEventListener('click', startTimer(), false);
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
<button>Start</button>
```

Comment: This has it's own problems though clicking start multiple times makes the timer go down even faster.

Comment: technically your answer does answer his question but adds some bugs, Check out my solution for reset + non colliding timeouts.

Comment: What bugs? I'd like to know.

Comment: The code was running the timeout again and again if you clicked start repeatedly. I'm not sure that was intended, if it was then I guess that's not a bug. I personally would prefer it to not behave like that but that's a questions of implementation preference at the end of the day. This is obviously based on the answer before your edited it. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71230737/revisions

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this could be improved.

- In this example we don't go below 0.
- We don't allow timeout collisions ( timeouts don't stack causing weird counting speeds ).
- We can reset to the original number when on 0.

```js
const c = document.getElementById('timer-counter')
const b = document.getElementById('start-button')

let timer = false
let timerCount = 30

b.addEventListener('click', start)

function decrement() {

    if(timerCount < 0) {
        timerCount = 30
        timer = false
        return
    }

    c.innerText = `Count: ${timerCount}`
    timerCount--

    timer = setTimeout(decrement, 200)
}

function start() {
    if(timer) return

    decrement()
}
```

```html
<div id="timer-counter"></div>
<button id="start-button">Start</button>
```